# Python3 verify if List Items are contained in read() result

Tags: python-3.x

I want to verify if Items from a List are contained in what i fetch by using string.read().
How do I do this:

```
if string.find(lisst):
 do_whatever()
elif string.find(lisst2):
 do_something_else()
```

Example is pretty basic, but that's all I want to do. I keep getting invalid syntax error. :(

```py
def verify(text):
    lisst = ['awesome','failed','trolling']
    lisst2 = ['boring','bad']
    s = requests.get(text)
    t = s.read()
    if t.find(lisst):
        print("Someone was awesome, failing or trolling!")
    elif t.find(lisst2)
        print("Something retarded happened")
```

error is thrown at elif t.find(lisst2), so I need a workaround.

```
    elif any(n in t for n in lisst2):
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post the actual error message, and the actual code that caused it.

Comment: Don't call a variable `list`. Pending the exact traceback: [`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) does not accept a list as input.

Comment: i already tried any to fix the problem so error message is an other one, but it fails on elif, can someone tell me why? >.<

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to do something in an if block if a string contains any the elements of a list.

```
if any(str in aVeryLongStringData for str in myList):
    doStuff()
```

If you want to check if your data contains all of the elements on your list, you can just change "any" to "all"

```
if all(str in aVeryLongStringData for str in myList):
    doStuff()
```